control of pneumatic starter of gas turbine engine
Pneumatic differentiator(red ellipse) is a safety device which is fitted to the regulator&shut off valve at upstream of pneumatic starter of gas turbine engine. Do you have any idea on its working principle?

why don't you ask what is its working principle? ... the question you asked gives a simple yes/no answer

Driven by the pressure difference across the butterfly.
